# Hue UI is not accessible from a remote host

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hue, webhdfs

I'am trying to use Hue as a file browser for HDFS. So for that I have clone the hue repository and build the app with the following commands given in [README.md](https://github.com/cloudera/hue/blob/master/README.md) of the hue repository.

```
git clone https://github.com/cloudera/hue.git
cd hue
make apps
build/env/bin/hue runserver
```

Hue UI is accessible in local machine using default port using the url http://localhost:8000 and everything works fine. But when I use my machine ip address http://x.x.x.x:8000 and try to access the Hue UI it keeps on processing and waiting.

Other observations -:

- I can ping from remote machine to the host machine.
- There is no firewall blocking the ports. (checked with nmap port scanner)
- Machines are in same network.
- I can access other ports for Hadoop NameNodes UI and DataNodes.
- Changing the `http_host` in hue.ini doesn't affect the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to the issue.. First hue run on a CherryPy web server so starting server by command `build/env/bin/hue runserver` will start the development server where `hue.ini` configuration is neglected.

So the correct command to start the production server after setting up correct configuration in `hue.ini` file is `build/env/bin/hue runcpserver`. Then I was able to access it using remote host without any problem. You also can use `supervisor` to start the production server. More information about that can be found [here](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/cdh_ig_hue_admin.html)

Comment: Thank you an ocean to share your solution :)

Answer (score 1):

The ideal setup for Hue is configuring a reverse proxy ([Nginx](http://gethue.com/using-nginx-to-speed-up-hue-3-8-0/) or [Apache HTTP](http://gethue.com/how-to-run-hue-with-the-apache-server/), for example)

However, you should refer to the [Configuration documentation](http://cloudera.github.io/hue/latest/admin-manual/manual.html#web-server-configuration) to externally run the server outside of 127.0.0.1

```
[desktop]
  # Webserver listens on this address and port
  http_host=0.0.0.0
  http_port=8888
```